# C# Files not getting added in a custom project template - VS 2017

Tags: visual-studio-2017

I am creating a New Project Template in VS2017 based on ASPNET Core Web API project.  I have followed steps as outlined here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-create-project-templates

The zip file contains all the files (C# files).
When the new project is created based on the above project template, none of the C# files are added to the project.

Are there any special steps or settings to include the C# files?

Answer (score 2):

I know this response is late but it may save someone else some other day.

I had this issue as well and i realized the solution was to include the CreateInPlace tag as a child of the TemplateData tag in the .vsTemplate for the project.

Unzip the zip file and update this template file. Add the following line

```
<CreateInPlace>true</CreateInPlace>
```

as a child of the TemplateData tag

```
<TemplateData></TemplateData>
```